# Angular 2 : Change an ng Smart table row into a routerlink

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I'm working on ng2 Smart Table, and I want to change a row (or even a cell data) into a link (`routerlink`), I'm currently using this method in order to get some data of my row :

```
onUserRowSelect(event) 
{ 
    console.log('user row select: ', event);
    this.selected = event.selected;
    console.log('selected list: ', this.selected);
    this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"]);
    console.log("this is a test ");
}
```

Of course the event is coming from the HTML file, 
I'm using `this.router.navigate` to navigate to my other page, the problem is that an error is always occurring telling me

**TypeError: this.router is undefined
    Stack trace:
    [1215]/SmartTables.prototype.onUserRowSelect@http:**

can anyone tell me 1) what's the problem here, and 2) how can I extract the data coming from the event (it's returning an `Object`). Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your settings configure like this in the column

```
objektelinks: {
title: 'Objektelink',
type: 'custom',
renderComponent: LinkViewComponent,
},
```

create a render component like this

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from 
'@angular/core';
import { ViewCell } from 'ng2-smart-table';

@component({
selector: 'ngx-link-view',
template: <a [routerLink]= "['/auth/register']"> Objekte </a>,
})
export class LinkViewComponent implements ViewCell, OnInit {
renderValue: string;

@input() value: string | number;
@input() rowData: any;

@output() save: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

ngOnInit() {
enter code here
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently fighting with similar issue, but.. 
This might help you:

1. Problem #1

   - Have you imported Router from '@angular/core'? If not: *import { Router /* ... */ } from "@angular/router";*
   - Have passed to constructor Router object? If not do something like this: *constructor(private **router:Router**) {/* ... */}*
2. Problem #2

   If you log your Object, then in the browser console you can see this Object as expandable list. You can find there whatever you want.

   How to extract your data? Probably:

   *event.data.someValue;*

I hope I helped at some point.

Comment: yes, all of that works for me, I'm only stuck with the router problem ... trying to solve it